# How to ping over MTProto proxy?

Tags: proxy, telegram, ping, mtproto

I want to retrieve the ping value of MTProto proxies to find out if the proxy is working or not.

If you have worked with the Telegram interface, you would have seen that in the proxies section, it shows a ping value in (ms) for each of the proxies.
I am looking for a solution to retrieve that value.